# How to only pop a git stash for a specific file in the project?

Tags: git, diff

How to only pop a git stash for only a specific file in the project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the restore command
`git restore -s stash@{0} -- <filename>`

Comment: great, simple answer! Please add your answer to the linked similar question. I almost did not see your answer and would have used a more convoluted way to achieve the same.